# Tesseract OCR - recognize checkboxes as word

Tags: ocr, tesseract

for a customer I want to teach Tesseract to recognize checkboxes as a word. It worked fine when Tesseract should recognize a empty checkbox.

This command in combination with [this](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/a-guide-on-ocr-with-tesseract-3-03/) tutorial worked like a charm and Tesseract was able to find empty checkboxes and interpret them to "[_]":

```
tesseract -psm 10 deu2.unchecked1.exp0.JPG deu2.unchecked1.exp0.box nobatch box.train
```

Here is my command to successful analyze a document:

```
tesseract test.png test -l deu1+deu2
```

Then I tried to train a checked checkbox, but got this error:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.00 with Leptonica
FAIL!
APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 1/[X] ((60,30),(314,293)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob
APPLY_BOXES:
   Boxes read from boxfile:       1
   Boxes failed resegmentation:       1
   Found 0 good blobs.
Generated training data for 0 words
```

Does anyone have an idea how to teach Tesseract recognize checked checkboxes as well?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much more tries I figured out that it is of course possible to teach Tesseract different kind of letters. But as I know today, there is no possibility to teach Tesseract a sign which is not conform to some "visual rules" of a letter. For example: A letter is always one connected line of ink, at most a combination of ink and "something outside it" (for example: i,ä,ö,ü) Problem here ist that there is nothing what is similiat to checkbox (one object *in* antother object) This leads for Tesseract to irritations and crashes.

Comment: But aren't Chinese characters similar? I mean why checkbox recognition is so difficult ? I am also facing the same problem

Comment: As far as I know Chinese character are never "a sign **in** a sign". (Maybe I am wrong because I never had any deeper experiences with Chinese) So the rule of connected ink blots would apply there.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for recognition of empty check box but no success. I was able to configure Tesseract to recognize Sigma/theta/integral/Indian Rupee symbol but not checkbox.

Comment: @ChristophBätz How did you finally solve your issue about OMR (optical mark recognition)? Do you found any local running library or which external service/API did you use now?

Comment: @timguy it was solved with ABBYY by another colleague later.